# Ensure Unique Ribbon Tab For Excel Add-In

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, excel-addins, office-addins

I've created an office add in with a custom ribbon. All works as expected i.e. I see my controls in the tab I create, until I install another 3rd party add-in which gets installed in the same tab. Is there any way to ensure my add in doesn't share it's tab with other add ins?

Thanks in adv!

Comment: Please show your ribbon xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following:

- In VS, select the XYZRibbon.cs
- Select the default tab
- In the properties window, expand ControlId
- Set ControlIdType to "Custom"

After that, I redeployed and my add-in had a tab to itself.

Hth